# Отсортировать список пар по значению второго элемента в паре и вернуть значения первых элементов пар

Tags: python, python-3.x

Доброе время суток.
Не могу реализовать алгоритм:

есть список:

```
i=[['a','1'],['cc','1'],['b','2'],['aa','1'],['ee','3']
```

Нужно получить списки:

```
[['a','1'], ['cc','1']] ['aa','1'] ['b','2'] ['ee','3']
```

Т.е. проще говоря словами. Нужно вывести весь список, но группировать по два элемента, если нет пары, то оставить один элемент.

Comment: вы хотите отсортировать список по значению второго элемента в паре и вернуть значения первых элементов пар?

Comment: да, именно так.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, видимо, в задаче надо просто отсортировать пары элементов по второму элементу, ограничение на пары - избыточное

```
_ = {}
result = []

for k, val in i:
    if _.get(val):
        _[val].append(k)
        continue
    _[val] = [k]

for k in sorted(_.keys()):
    result.extend(_[k])
```

Собрал по-очереди все первые элементы, зависимые от вторых
И по сортированному списку просто забирал подсписки, расширяя результирующий.

Алгоритм, безусловно, можно оптимизировать.

Comment: `list(map(itemgetter(0), sorted(pairs, key=itemgetter(1))))`

Comment: Выглядит как-то сложно...

Comment: `[t[0] for t in sorted(i, key=lambda x: x[1])]`

Comment: @MaxU, опередили :)

Comment: Сори, не уточнил: в выводе должны быть пары. 
a,1
cc,1

Если остался один элемент в списке, то и его вывести.
Основная задача, собрать файлы в каталоге попарно, оставшейся файл положить отдельно.

Comment: @Дмитрий, приведите пример того что вы хотите получить (в его конечной форме [без "и т.д.", "и т.п."]) в вопросе вместо того, чтобы описывать это словами. Например: хочу получить следующий список `[['a', 1], ...]` (целиком, чтобы было понятно что вы хотите получить)